# Security in grails

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm looking for a security plugin for a grails project.
Spring security core 1.2.7.3 looks awesome but it seems that it's not under development for almost a year. Does anyone knows if that is the case?

Also are there any other good plugins?

Also i'm using mongodb and wanted to know if spring security core is compatible with mongo

Thanks!
Roy

Comment: I use spring-security-core in my project. Do you have any special requirements for security plugin, which are not handled by spring-security-core?

Comment: All that i need is handled by spring-security. My only concern is that the plugin was not updated for a very long time while spring security is on continuous development (i think version 3.2 right now)

Comment: Also i'm using mongodb and wanted to know if spring security core is compatible with mongo

Comment: spring-security plugin is compatible with mongodb. I have used spring-security plugin with mongodb (2.4) without any issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) again. It's supported by SpringSource. If no updates, no need in them. Don't think they just forget to update.

Comment: True, there aren't any pressing issues. There hasn't been activity in the repo because I've been working on version 2.0 locally.